# Bootstrap tooltip is not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.15

in my Angular 2 App. In Which tooltip is not working properly. code snippet is as follows

```
<input type="text" id="airport" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Error message goes here." data-placement="bottom">
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: <input type="text" 
data-toggle="tooltip" title="Error message goes here." data-placement="bottom">

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: tooltip styles is not working as regular tooltip like arrow and black backgrund. but message is coming at the mentioned position

Comment: have you enabled the tooltip jQuery Script?

Comment: no do i need to enable it. if so where do i need to enable ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Using the bootstrap-css-provided, jquery-based tooltip component? Or using the ng-bootstrap-provided, angular-based tooltip component. If the former, read and apply the bootstrap-css documentation. If using the latter, read and apply the ng-bootstrap documentation. Don't try the instructions of one to use the other: that won't work.

Comment: Also note that ng-bootstrap is based on bootstrap 4, not bootstrap 3. One more thing you missed when (not) reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> Please Add this function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
```